How do I calculate R^2 for only a subset of the data used to create a model (GLMER) in R?
I have a generalized linear mixed model fitted to data from several populations using the function glmer in the lme4 package. I'd like to know whether the model fits better to data in one population than the others and I'd like to have a neat way of reporting this quantitatively. I can calculate the R squared for this model using the function R2_nakagawa from the performance package. Is there a way to remake the model object with the same fit but with only a subset of the data (i.e. one population) and get the R^2 of that model object? Or am I missing an easier way to do what I want to do?

The update function should be what you are looking for.
library(lme4)
library(performance)

data(cbpp)

Start with a model containing all of the data.
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
             data = cbpp, family = binomial)

Make a new grouping variable and run the models again on each level.
ccbpp$group <- rep(paste("Group.", 1:2), each=nrow(cbpp)/2)

gm.group1 <- update(gm1, data=subset(cbpp, subset=group=="Group.1"))
gm.group2 <- update(gm1, data=subset(cbpp, subset=group=="Group.2"))

r2_nakagawa(gm.group1)
# R2 for Mixed Models

  Conditional R2: 0.770
     Marginal R2: 0.551

r2_nakagawa(gm.group2)
# R2 for Mixed Models

  Conditional R2: 0.809
     Marginal R2: 0.287

Or more conveniently using split and lapply:
lapply(split(cbpp, cbpp$group), \(x) r2_nakagawa(update(gm1, data=x)))
$`Group. 1`
# R2 for Mixed Models

  Conditional R2: 0.770
     Marginal R2: 0.551

$`Group. 2`
# R2 for Mixed Models

  Conditional R2: 0.809
     Marginal R2: 0.287


Thank you, this is interesting but I have 2 problems with this: 1) it throws up an error if you subset such that only one level remains of an effect and 2) I don't understand how to get it not to refit the model. The documentation says it refits by default, implying you can change that, but I don't see how to do it. I guess solving the second problem might solve the first.

I need your data to help further

Using your example, if you subset using period, e.g.
update(gm1, data=subset(cbpp, period=="1"))
this returns "Error in contrasts<-(*tmp*, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels"
This is because it's refitting the model to the subset which I don't want to do. What I want to do is quantify how well the model fits to herd "1" vs herd "2", ideally in a way that's easy to grok like an R2
